# How to make text spannable in textview in android

Tags: android

I have one textview where i am displaying below String  .

"I agree to receive recurring automated marketing text messages (e.g. cart reminders) at the phone number provided. Consent is not a condition to purchase. Msg & data rates may apply. Msg frequency varies. Reply HELP for help and STOP to cancel. View our Terms of Service and Privacy Policy"

I am trying to make Terms of Service , Privacy Policy make as link so that i can apply click and open new page i have tried below code to make link and click but i am able to make link both text but View our Terms of Service is not changes color of link but i am able to Privacy Policy .

```
 private void customTextView(TextView view) {
            SpannableStringBuilder spanTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                    "I agree to receive recurring automated marketing text messages (e.g. cart reminders) at the phone number provided. Consent is not a condition to purchase. Msg &amp; data rates may apply. Msg frequency varies. Reply HELP for help and STOP to cancel. View our ");
            spanTxt.append("Terms of Service");
            spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, spanTxt.length(), 0);
            spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Terms of services Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, spanTxt.length() - "Term of services".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
            view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            view.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
            spanTxt.append(" and");
            spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, spanTxt.length(), 0);
            spanTxt.append(" Privacy Policy");
            spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Privacy Policy Clicked",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }, spanTxt.length() - " Privacy Policy".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
            view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
            view.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        }
```

here actual output

[image]

but expected i want to make orange color Terms condtion text also . please help me what i am doing wrong with this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

add below line

```
spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), spanTxt.length() -  " Privacy Policy".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
```

like this

```
SpannableStringBuilder spanTxt = new SpannableStringBuilder(
                "I agree to receive recurring automated marketing text messages (e.g. cart reminders) at the phone number provided. Consent is not a condition to purchase. Msg &amp; data rates may apply. Msg frequency varies. Reply HELP for help and STOP to cancel. View our ");

        spanTxt.append("Terms of Service");
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, spanTxt.length(), 0);
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Terms of services Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, spanTxt.length() - "Term of services".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
        view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        view.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

        spanTxt.append(" and");
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLACK), 0, spanTxt.length(), 0);

        spanTxt.append(" Privacy Policy");
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View widget) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Privacy Policy Clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, spanTxt.length() - " Privacy Policy".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
        // FOR SET TEXT COLOR
        spanTxt.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), spanTxt.length() -  " Privacy Policy".length(), spanTxt.length(), 0);
        view.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
        view.setText(spanTxt, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```